# ASP.Net Members in web.config remove provider

Tags: asp.net, membership-provider, aspnetdb

I'm trying to avoid the ASPNETDB.mdf file to be added to my project.

I have this in my config file:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" defaultUrl="Default.aspx" protection="All">
    <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
      <user name="admin" password="Qwe456"/>
      <user name="Murergruppe" password="2012m"/>
      <user name="Skift-a" password="2012a"/>
      <user name="Skift-b" password="2012b"/>
      <user name="Skift-c" password="2012c"/>
      <user name="Skift-d" password="2012d"/>
      <user name="Skift-e" password="2012e"/>
    </credentials>
  </forms>
</authentication>
```

Then i've turned of the creation of ASPNETDB.mdf in machine.config

then it says it can't find the file. then I add:

```
<membership>
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add type="Personal.Providers.WebConfigMembershipProvider" name="WebConfigMembershipProvider"/> 
  </providers>
</membership>
```

But then it says the default provider must be specified. What to do when i don't have any other providers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <membership defaultProvider="WebConfigMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="20">
   <providers>
.....
```

You may specify the default one.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think my provider is working right now, can I just;
<membership>
    <providers>
        <clear /> 
    </providers>
</membership>

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you need. You don't need the Membership in you application?

Comment: see if this help you: http://madskristensen.net/post/XML-membership-provider-for-ASPNET-20.aspx

Comment: Well i don't need anything. I have userdata in web.config as seen above. So I only want to logg inn to these. But the application also want an membership provider. So I don't understand why I need to write one, when I don't need to use it?

Comment: But how does the application know the users? How does the application knows if the logged user is Skift-a ? My advice would be to use the XML implementation on the link I sent before. Or create your own membership provider. 

Have you tried to remove the <membership> section?

Comment: see this : http://vishalnayan.wordpress.com/2011/03/22/creating-credential-store-for-form-authentication-in-asp-net-3-5/

Comment: <configuration>
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name="MyApp" path="/" loginUrl="login.aspx"
           protection="All" timeout="10">
      <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
        <user name="billjones" password="test" />
        <user name="marthasmith" password="test" />
        <user name="joesoap" password="test" />
      </credentials>
    </forms>
  </authentication>

  <authorization>
    <allow users="billjones,marthasmith,joesoap" />
    <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>

</system.web>
</configuration>

Comment: from here: http://p2p.wrox.com/asp-net-1-1/17926-forms-authentication-credentials.html